# Should git questions be asked here

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct site for Version Control questions](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/579/what-is-the-correct-site-for-version-control-questions)

Wouldn't they be more appropriate on StackOverflow unless they pertain to maintaining a git server?

[How to tell which local branch is tracking which remote branch in Git?](https://serverfault.com/questions/175052/how-to-tell-which-local-branch-is-tracking-which-remote-branch-in-git)

Comment: Dup/similar to this. http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/579/what-is-the-correct-site-for-version-control-questions

Answer (score 2):

I think it the older question we mostly decided that VCS questions belong on stackoverflow unless the question was specifically about the server administration related to a particular VCS, the question was about how to use the VCS to perform a system administration task (etckeeper, tracking config management stuff).

OTOH, one might argue that really generic stuff belongs over on superuser

Comment: Just today I dealt with a flag from a SF-mod about a [mis-migrated dev-tools question](http://serverfault.com/q/354055/3038). Specifically, "dev tools and usage thereof are topical on SO".

Answer (score 1):

I'm inclined to agree with you in that only the server aspect is on topic on SF but that doesn't mean all other Git (or other VCS systems) questions should be sent to SO.

The example you cite is a very good one of a question that doesn't belong on SO any more than it belongs on SF. It's not about the administration of a Git server. Nor is it a programming question. The question is relevant to users of Git, which covers all manner of people including, but not limited to, system admins and programmers. Under the circumstances I'd leave it alone.