# What kinds of Network questions belong to Serverfault and what belong to superuser?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Networking - always an SF topic?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/526/networking-always-an-sf-topic)

I saw in serverfault's faq, one kind of question belonging to this site is network. So I was wondering what kinds of Network questions belong to Serverfault and what belong to superuser?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1):

If it's a network that you'd hire a SysAdmin to manage, it belongs on SF.
If it's a home network, or something you'd typically find in a home setting, it belongs on SU.

See the [Official Meta FAQ Question](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/62/how-does-server-fault-work-the-community-faq) for more details.